# Logging data from High Precision AD/DA board using Raspberry Pi 3B

Tags: python, csv, raspberry-pi3, adc

I have a High Precision AD/DA board from [waveshare](https://www.waveshare.com/High-Precision-AD-DA-Board.htm) with Raspberry Pi 3B (running on Raspbian). With this setup, I get a sampling rate of above 20KPS at my terminal display.

However, I can write only 27 samples in 1s in my CSV file. I am using [this Python code](https://github.com/waveshare/High-Precision-AD-DA-Board/tree/master/RaspberryPI/ADS1256/python3) for writing to a CSV file. It seems my code is not optimized for writing at a higher sampling rate.

Could you let me know how can I write the data to my CSV file above 10 KPS sampling rate?

Note: I use following statment for writing to a CSV file :

```
data=str(a[0])+','+str(a[1])+','+str(a[2])+','+str(a[3])+','+str(a[4])+','+str(a[5])+','+str(a[6])+','+str(a[7])+','+str(time.time())
```

So I am storing each row in the above data variable and then writing it to the file using standard process.

Thanks